# Controlling the maximum value of an unsigned int

Tags: java, unsigned-integer

If I have a 4-bit unsigned integer, the maximum value is 15. If the value is 0 and I subtract 1, I get 15. I can increase the bit size by 1 and have the maximum value be 31, and so on and so forth. This is great, but I want to be able to control the maximum value to be values other than 2^n - 1.

How do I create a custom type such that I can control this maximum value when I instantiate it while maintaining the same efficiency as an unsigned int?

The use case for this I am thinking of is so that I can treat an array of elements like a circularly linked list without using a linked list. Sorry if this is a stupid question!

Comment: just use **mode** operator (**%**) for getting pre ornext element for circularly linked list. For exmaple, the length is n, and index is i, then the pre index is `(i-1+n)%n` and the next index is `(i+1)%n`

Comment: Java does not have unsigned types, period.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- ...except `char`.

Comment: @jsheeran Touché.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the modulus operator `%` which returns the remainder between two operands. For example, if you wanted the maximum value to be 13, assuming you're indexing with a variable `i`, you can do `array[i % 14]` which will result in the index only being in the range 0 -> 13. I'm not sure if there is a way to create a custom type with this property, unless you created a class and implemented the methods for the add and subtract operators to create the same behavior as with your unsigned integer. Here's the gist of it:

```
public class MaxInt {
    private final int max;
    private int value;

    public MaxInt(int max, int value) {
        this.max = max;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public MaxInt plus(int a) {
        return new MaxInt(this.max, (this.value + a) % (this.max + 1));
    }

    public MaxInt minus(int a) {
        return new MaxInt(this.max, (this.value - a) % (this.max + 1));
    }

    public getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

Then you could do the same with `new MaxInt(13, 0)` and your value will be between 0 -> 13.

Comment: I see! I completely forgot about that usage of the operator. Thanks!

Comment: @StephenLee no problem, I added an edit if you want to try wrapping that functionality in a class to create your custom type